# Getting An unhandled exception occurred error when adding bootstrap to angular

Tags: angular

[Getting this error while adding bootstrap to angular project "**An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\Velocity\Capstone-Project\gipher-app\node_modules'
See "C:\Users\91789\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-B1BCBh\angular-errors.log" for further details.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4BQN.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In angular.json file, I had given bootstrap path like this

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```

So, changed it to

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```

Problem solved!